# Jsp taking long time to respond

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

What causes output`_jsp.java` take so long to respond. It consumes around 90% of the total response time of my struts action.

It is taking long time to process this line        `_jspx_th_s_005fproperty_005f0.setPageContext(_jspx_page_context);`

```
package org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;


public final class output_jsp extends org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent {

private static final javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory _jspxFactory =
      javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getDefaultFactory();

private static java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long> _jspx_dependants;

private org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool _005fjspx_005ftagPool_005fs_005fproperty_0026_005fvalue_005fescape_005fnobody;

private javax.el.ExpressionFactory _el_expressionfactory;
private org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager _jsp_instancemanager;

public java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long> getDependants() {
return _jspx_dependants;
}

public void _jspInit() {
_005fjspx_005ftagPool_005fs_005fproperty_0026_005fvalue_005fescape_005fnobody = org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool.getTagHandlerPool(getServletConfig());
_el_expressionfactory = _jspxFactory.getJspApplicationContext(getServletConfig().getServletContext()).getExpressionFactory();
_jsp_instancemanager = org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(getServletConfig());
}

 public void _jspDestroy() {
_005fjspx_005ftagPool_005fs_005fproperty_0026_005fvalue_005fescape_005fnobody.release();
}

public void _jspService(final javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, final javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)
    throws java.io.IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException {

final javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext pageContext;
javax.servlet.http.HttpSession session = null;
final javax.servlet.ServletContext application;
final javax.servlet.ServletConfig config;
javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out = null;
final java.lang.Object page = this;
javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter _jspx_out = null;
javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext _jspx_page_context = null;


try {
  response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
  pageContext = _jspxFactory.getPageContext(this, request, response,
            null, true, 8192, true);
  _jspx_page_context = pageContext;
  application = pageContext.getServletContext();
  config = pageContext.getServletConfig();
  session = pageContext.getSession();
  out = pageContext.getOut();
  _jspx_out = out;

  out.write('\n');
  out.write('\n');
  if (_jspx_meth_s_005fproperty_005f0(_jspx_page_context))
    return;
} catch (java.lang.Throwable t) {
  if (!(t instanceof javax.servlet.jsp.SkipPageException)){
    out = _jspx_out;
    if (out != null && out.getBufferSize() != 0)
      try {
        if (response.isCommitted()) {
          out.flush();
        } else {
          out.clearBuffer();
        }
      } catch (java.io.IOException e) {}
    if (_jspx_page_context != null) _jspx_page_context.handlePageException(t);
    else throw new ServletException(t);
  }
} finally {
  _jspxFactory.releasePageContext(_jspx_page_context);
}
}

private boolean _jspx_meth_s_005fproperty_005f0(javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext _jspx_page_context)
      throws java.lang.Throwable {
javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext pageContext = _jspx_page_context;
javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out = _jspx_page_context.getOut();
//  s:property
org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.PropertyTag _jspx_th_s_005fproperty_005f0 = (org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.PropertyTag) _005fjspx_005ftagPool_005fs_005fproperty_0026_005fvalue_005fescape_005fnobody.get(org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.PropertyTag.class);
_jspx_th_s_005fproperty_005f0.setPageContext(_jspx_page_context);//this particular line is taking too long to respond.

_jspx_th_s_005fproperty_005f0.setParent(null);
// /WEB-INF/jsp/output.jsp(3,0) name = value type = java.lang.String reqTime = false required = false fragment = false deferredValue = false expectedTypeName = null deferredMethod = false methodSignature = null
_jspx_th_s_005fproperty_005f0.setValue("output");
// /WEB-INF/jsp/output.jsp(3,0) name = escape type = java.lang.String reqTime = false required = false fragment = false deferredValue = false expectedTypeName = null deferredMethod = false methodSignature = null
_jspx_th_s_005fproperty_005f0.setEscape(false);
int _jspx_eval_s_005fproperty_005f0 = _jspx_th_s_005fproperty_005f0.doStartTag();
if (_jspx_th_s_005fproperty_005f0.doEndTag() == javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag.SKIP_PAGE) {
  _005fjspx_005ftagPool_005fs_005fproperty_0026_005fvalue_005fescape_005fnobody.reuse(_jspx_th_s_005fproperty_005f0);
  return true;
}
_005fjspx_005ftagPool_005fs_005fproperty_0026_005fvalue_005fescape_005fnobody.reuse(_jspx_th_s_005fproperty_005f0);
return false;
}
}
```

This here is the JSP

```
<%@page contentType="text/plain; charset=utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<s:property value="output" escape="false"/>
```

Please help me out on what could be the reason for long response time and what could be done to tweak the response time.

Comment: How did you measure it? Also post the source code.

Comment: What are you `output`-ing?